# Problems with getting values out of nested dictionary in Swift 3 and Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I parse JSON with this :

```
 let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: geocodingResultsData as Data, options: .mutableContainers)
```

and get the following nested dictionary as a result

```
{ response =  { GeoObjectCollection = { featureMember =  
( 
{  GeoObject = { Point =  { pos = "40.275713 59.943413"; };   };  },
{  GeoObject = { Point =  { pos = "40.273162 59.944292"; };  };  } 
);
};
};
}
```

I'm trying to get the values of coordinates out of this dictionary and save them into new latutudeString and longitudeString variables

Until Xcode 8 GM it worked for me with this code:

```
 if let jsonCoordinatesString: String = dictionary["response"]!!["GeoObjectCollection"]!!["featureMember"]!![0]["GeoObject"]!!["Point"]!!["pos"]!! as? String {

            var latLongArray = jsonCoordinatesString.components(separatedBy: " ")

            let latitudeString = latLongArray[1]
            let longitudeString = latLongArray[0]

        }
```

But since I've installed Xcode 8 GM i receive an error:

> Type Any has no Subscript members

[image]

How to fix it it Swift 3 with Xcode 8 ? I've read that I can cast it but don't know exactly how to make it work with my nested dictionary in swift 3 with the latest Xcode. I've read [can't resolve "Ambiguous use of subscript"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389845/cant-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-subscript) but it really did not helped me in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't resolve "Ambiguous use of subscript"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39389845/cant-resolve-ambiguous-use-of-subscript)

Comment: I've checked the topic @Larme but it didn't help in my case, so still don't know how to solve my problem in Swift 3 / Xcode 8. If I cast dictionary as [AnyObject], i still receive an error that  type [AnyObject] has no Subscript members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data has this type in Swift:

```
[String: [String: [String: [[String: [String: [String: String]]]]]]]
```

I would avoid using such a too deeply nested type, but you can write something like this, if you dare use it:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case invalidStructure
}
do {
    guard let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: geocodingResultsData as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: [String: [String: [[String: [String: [String: String]]]]]]] else {
        throw MyError.invalidStructure
    }
    if let jsonCoordinatesString: String = dictionary["response"]?["GeoObjectCollection"]?["featureMember"]?[0]["GeoObject"]?["Point"]?["pos"] {

        var latLongArray = jsonCoordinatesString.components(separatedBy: " ")

        let latitudeString = latLongArray[1]
        let longitudeString = latLongArray[0]

    }
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

But you may be hiding some irrelevant members of the JSON data, which might break this `as?` conversion.

So, you can go step by step, in some cases "need to" in Swift 3, like this:

```
do {
    guard let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: geocodingResultsData as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
        throw MyError.invalidStructure
    }
    if
        let response = dictionary["response"] as? [String: AnyObject],
        let geoObjectCollection = response["GeoObjectCollection"] as? [String: AnyObject],
        let featureMember = geoObjectCollection["featureMember"] as? [[String: AnyObject]],
        !featureMember.isEmpty,
        let geoObject = featureMember[0]["GeoObject"] as? [String: AnyObject],
        let point = geoObject["Point"] as? [String: AnyObject],
        let jsonCoordinatesString = point["pos"] as? String
    {
        var latLongArray = jsonCoordinatesString.components(separatedBy: " ")

        let latitudeString = latLongArray[1]
        let longitudeString = latLongArray[0]

    }
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

(`let`s are mandatory for each Optional-bindings in Swift 3. And you can change all `AnyObject`s to `Any`s, if you prefer.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have not specify the type of `dictionary` object, you need to explicitly specify the type of `dictionary` object as `Dictionary` like this way.

```
let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: geocodingResultsData as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]

if let response = dictionary["response"] as? [String: Any], 
   let geoObjectCollection = response["GeoObjectCollection"] as? [String: Any],
   let featureMember = geoObjectCollection["featureMember"] as? [[String: Any]] {

     if let geoObject = featureMember[0]["GeoObject"] as? [String: Any],
        let point = geoObject["Point"] as? [String: String] {
            let latLongArray = point["pos"].components(separatedBy: " ")
            let latitudeString = latLongArray[1]
            let longitudeString = latLongArray[0]
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but still receive Type "Any" has no subscript members, I tried let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: geocodingResultsData as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any] and let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: geocodingResultsData as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: AnyObject] but in both cases get Type 'Any" has no subscript eambers